# What does CNError.Code.communicationError error mean?

Tags: ios, ios-contacts

I can see this error on some users (very very little percent) when trying to load contacts. The error is standard CNError, but I can not find information about the reason of its occuring. May be somebody can help?

Comment: Can you clarify? You have code that is loading from `CNContactStore`?

Comment: @benc I receive this error in CNContactStore method enumerateContacts, when trying to get all contacts. The error code is 1 which means communication error according to Apple guides.

Comment: I don't think the `CNContact` docs say much on this topic, esp that error.

I like what Todor is saying, so I think you need more info on when it happens. Are the users on cell data, if so what type? Are they mounting other CardDAV, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question! To be fair I am not sure if I know the answer, however I will try to explain my suspicions for the cause of this error. 
`Contacts framework` does not lookup just the database existing in a device when an app asks for contact data it also searches for contacts in other sources too, like your `iCloud` account, and returns back to the app unified contacts that originate from various sources.
The nature of this process indicates to me that this error could be related to the internet connection of the access to the `iCloud` contacts.
Again this is just a speculation and I can't confirm it. Maybe it would be worth if you try this on your own to simulate the behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for the idea I will try and write about results’